# Access to journals during pandemic

Tags: soft-question, journals

I have just graduated from the University of Chicago and no longer have access to online journal resources, but I cannot afford to pay for them directly. Normally, I would be able to access library resources for a small fee in the campus library. However, due to closures due to Covid-19, this is no longer an option.

[Previous responses](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/279740/access-to-papers-as-an-unaffiliated-individual) to a similar question often involve physical access to a library, which is impossible for many for the foreseeable future. They also consider some access to online resources, but I was wondering if there were any Covid-specific online resources which have come about given the recent crisis. Even if they are not specific to the crisis, online tools which are accessible now are increasingly important, so would be useful.

Comment: Do you know that the UC alumni access doesn't cover what you need?  (I've never made much use of it, and can't remember my password, so I can't check right now.)  Have you asked the library director (Brenda Johnson) whether they would be willing to grant access to resources for a fee?

Comment: There are several resources I have been looking for which I have lost access to (UC online access for students is vast). One is the Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society, which I was not able to find in their alumni resources. I have not reached out to Brenda Johnson; thanks for that! I have inquired with a librarian about whether I will have faculty resources, considering I will be teaching at their affiliated charter school, but have not heard back yet.

Comment: Do you still have VPN from UChicago? That will make it appear as if you are on campus and usually grants journal access. If not, do you still have a departmental unix account (assuming Chicago has one)?  It's possible to set up a proxy via a ssh tunnel and this also makes it seem like you are accessing the internet from on campus.

Comment: RBega2, I had not thought of that! Technically I am not sure if I should have access to UChicago's VPN software (on the website it doesn't say that I do, but also doesn't say that I don't). However, I just tried it out and it appears that at least for now I still have access! Thank you! Now the question is just whether I will still have it in the near future...

Comment: @JoePrevidi, I just dug up my password and tried, and I wasn't able to access the VPN or the proxy, so it looks like a time-limited thing.

Comment: There is an illegal Hub for Sci-ence that provides a lot of journal access, started in Kazakhstan. You shouldn't check it out, though.

Comment: On my opinion, a majority of recent math papers are available on the arXiv. Moreover, NSF requires that all NSF sponsored papers be deposited on another arxiv which is supposed to be available to all. I have never used this NSF source since I find most of what I need on arXiv.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko the arXiv availability of articles varies widely by field. Some areas don't have as much arXiv coverage as you would think. It's very much a sampling bias effect. Also, it doesn't help for old papers! I'd be interested to know the NSF-mandated website. Is this related to CHORUS?

Comment: @David Roberts: The reason why some people DO NOT post their papers on the arXiv totally escapes me. Probably they write their papers not to be read but for some other purpose.

Comment: Yes, it is Chorus, https://par.nsf.gov/search/term:%22eremenko%22 I just checked: it says that my papers that I downloaded a week ago will be available on June 21 2021. The papers I uploaded a year ago are available.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I asked the category theorist Mike Barr why he doesn't post on the arXiv, yet posts all his papers and books on his website (and he is not exactly pro-commercial publisher, either). He said he doesn't want people to get their hands on his .tex files. I don't understand it either.

Comment: @David Roberts: I don't understand: can you access .tex files via the arXiv?? How? I only see .pdf files available there.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko it's not a .tex file, but it is LaTeX: https://arxiv.org/e-print/1905.02537 so open it in your favourite editor (more generally, change /abs/ to /format/ in the url of any arXiv paper, and if the source is there, you can get it. I've grabbed good styles and macros this way)

Comment: Let us not also forget about the library genesis for books. "Slightly" illegal too, but you know...

Comment: Elsevier is giving remote access for university email accounts. At least my university email works. You have to just register using your university email

Comment: Something else you can try, if the article was published recently and the author is still active, is to email them and simply ask for a copy of the paper.

Comment: In my (rather limited) experiences, authors are usually more than happy to provide copies of their papers if you write to them personally. I've done this on a couple of occasions.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Let me try to summarize this long discussion in the comments. There are many free resources.

1. [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/). It is true that not all mathematicians post their papers on the arXiv, for various reasons. But some of those who don't, post them on their personal sites. There are also other depositories, for example in Europe (see 5 below).
2. [NSF depository](https://par.nsf.gov/search/). NSF's [stated policy](https://www.nsf.gov/news/special_reports/public_access/) is that all results of NSF-sponsored research "must be available to the public at most in 1 year since their publication". I checked: the site is somewhat confusing but it works.
3. Many journals are freely available, and many more make their papers available after some time (usually 4-5 years). When you choose a journal to publish your paper, take this into account! Here is a convenient [catalog of online journals](http://rzblx1.uni-regensburg.de/ezeit/fl.phtml?bibid=UBK&colors=7&lang=de&notation=SA-SP). I am sure many other libraries have similar catalogs; I find this one convenient. The journals with free access are marked green, with partial access yellow and red. Access may depend on your location or on the date of publication.
4. Finally there are "pirate" sites. Some of them may have huge collections, larger than many university libraries. They frequently change their names and location. Some keywords may be "bookfi" or "genesis" for books, and "sci-hub" for journal articles. (Some of them may be illegal in some countries).
5. A simple search on Google and especially on Google Scholar sometimes finds what you need. It could be a place you do not expect. Some saved/cached copy. Some preprint depository that you do not know. Some personal web site, etc.
6. The very important resource is MathScinet, which unfortunately has no free version. But its German competitor Zentralblatt Math is partially free. Whatever you search there, it gives you only 3 items for free. But by clever choice of search criteria
   you can obtain amazing results. For really old items, there is also
   [Jahrbuch](https://www.emis.de//MATH/JFM/full.html) which is free (it is a subset of Zentralblatt). For new papers, Google Scholar is excellent, especially if you know the author's name and title of the paper. It also sometimes finds you a free copy when available.

EDIT. I asked NSF, and they explained that all NSF-supported papers older than 1 year are
really available, though the site is somewhat confusing. One has to click on
the title of the paper, and then on a little square which says "pdf".

EDIT 2: I collected some links to free resources on [my web page](https://www.math.purdue.edu/~eremenko/).

EDIT 3: Zentralblatt Math is now free for all, full version. Thanks to the German government.

Comment: Even if these sites frequently change their names and location, you can usually find a valid URL on their [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sci-Hub) [pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_Genesis). (Your ISP may block that URL, though.)

Comment: Not just Jahrbuch, but [EuDML](https://eudml.org/) is excellent for older articles from European journals (hence lots of Springer). It usually gives a link to a free copy if there is one.

Comment: According to a recent [press release](https://www.fiz-karlsruhe.de/en/nachricht/zbmath-open-informationen-fuer-die-mathematik-werden-frei-zugaenglich), Zentralblatt Math will become free by 2021.

Comment: @JonCC: this is a great news of course. But let us wait and see: I suspect that they may be talking about some reduced free version (of the kind they currently have).

Answer (score 39):

Some are just too shy to actually give the concrete answer, so here it is:

## Sci-Hub: https://sci-hub.st

Pro-tip: Go to the WikipediA page of Sci-Hub to keep up with the new domains of Sci-Hub (since they have to constantly change them owing to the cancel culture brought down by academic publishers).

If you're looking for most scientific papers fetched by Sci-Hub check LibGen: https://libgen.is/scimag/

(The pro-tip mentioned above applies here as well)

Pro-tip2: If for whatever reason you can't access that website then you can simply get around this by installing the [Tor Browser](https://torproject.org/download) and accessing it from there.

I wish you fulfilling and safe mathematical readings.

Comment: Sci-Hub is already mentioned in a comment, as well as (indirectly) in Alexandre Eremenko's answer. Directly linking copyright-violating sites on MO is also [quite a contentious issue](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3953/what-to-do-when-a-post-contains-a-suspicious-link-possibly-with-copyrighted-m).

Comment: In this case, the OP using sci-hub would not represent a copyright violation. His university has already paid for subscriptions to the journals in question. In general, you are allowed to possess an electronic copy of a resource (book, article, journal) when you have already possessed or paid for a different copy. For example, if I have a copy of Dummit-Foote on my bookshelf in my office, I can legally download a pdf of it. I think the same applies here.

Comment: Here is another pro tip: very often you internet provider will not let you access any of the said "pirate" websites and prompt instead an error message. To circumvent this it's enough to change your DNS server (use e.g. google's one or whichever fits you best). A quick search on internet will teach you how to do that in a very few clicks, it's really simple and a life-changer (mathematically speaking, I mean, I never have anymore to log into any "nonpirate" VPN from my current institution or whatever to access the papers I need).

Comment: @leomonsaingeon Thanks for mentioning that. One comment though is that it's not always possible for example when countries like Russia block individual IPs as well. I think the safest bet here is to use the Tor Browser.

Comment: Even when you *do* have paid access, Sci-Hub is usually faster. Making a publisher's website recognize your institutional subscription can be a ridiculous rigmarole. But with Sci-Hub you just paste in the DoI and up comes the PDF. Perfect.

Comment: "His university has already paid for subscriptions to the journals in question." What university? He's a graduate, so he's not affiliated with them anymore.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda: The mentions in comments and other answers are euphemistic and unclear; if illegal sites to be discussed at all, it seems better and more professional to do so frankly and explicitly.  It’s good to consider the legal and ethical issues, as discussed in the meta question you linked, and to avoid such sites for literature links in ordinary MO questions/answers.  But on a question like this one, where the question itself is “what such sites exist”, it seems pretty denialist to avoid them.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I think that's a good way to put it, and aligns with my personal view on the matter. I think the main point of contention lies in *linking* the sites, rather than avoiding talking about them as if they don't exist. Personally, I don't mind seeing links or discussion, but would probably like to see a disclaimer added about the ethical/legal issues surrounding it. My comment was mostly in this direction.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda FWIW WikipediA also links to them, why should that be a problem to SE when WikipediA already does it without any issues? (Just linking something doesn't mean one is supporting it, endorsing it, encouraging its use, ...etc)

Comment: @user161087 why are you capitalizing the final "a" in Wikipedia?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Absolutely. Plus, let's not be too hasty in calling Sci-Hub "illegal". None of us are lawyers. Just because someone like an Elsevier spokesperson claims it's illegal, doesn't mean it is. Just because some ISPs have been pressured to block access, doesn't mean it's illegal. And just because it's illegal in your country, doesn't mean it's illegal in other people's.

Comment: @JoePrevidi Sorry I took their logo too literally, yes "Wikipedia" is the correct version of their name.

Comment: @user161087 I do not think it is a problem. Others do, as indicated in the link. Others don't. This has been a contentious issue for a while, and I think it is important to mention that it has been.

Comment: @TomLeinster I would guess that violating copyright millions of times is illegal in most jurisdictions, and courts have very definitely decided against Sci-Hub in the US. Some hold the position, though, that providing access to the scientific and research literature to those that cannot otherwise get it, and especially at a time of a global health crisis, is the _moral_ thing to do, despite the law.

Comment: Also, note there is a fine line between accessing something the library already has (and so issues around legality of the copy become much less clear), and "accidentally" accessing something it doesn't have. If my library has a book in an inaccessible crate in a long-term storage facility (don't ask), and will have to fly in a copy from interstate so I can check if it is what I need, then I feel no compunctions about checking it out on LibGen. It saves money, time and CO2. If I look up something on Sci-Hub my uni does not have access to, then I feel I need to do so knowing that.

Comment: @DavidWhite Unless the copyright holder has *explicitly* granted you the right to other versions, including an electronic version, then you most definitely do *not* have a right to an electronic copy *just* from owning a print copy of something. Publishers may give a deal where you get both a print and electronic version, but it's certainly not the default, and there's nothing inherent that grants you the right to a copy in another format. For the specific situation you describe, you may have a right to an electronic copy, but it's not something you, or anyone, should *assume* you/they have.

Comment: @Makyen: I strongly disagree. If you want to change my mind, I'll need more than a MathOverflow comment. Perhaps you have some sources you could cite? I can dig around for the source where I learned the fact I stated in my comment.

Comment: @DavidWhite When you purchase something, you obtain ownership of it and have ownership rights in *that specific copy*. Making that purchase doesn't inherently grant you rights to something else, unless that was part of the purchase contract. You're asserting you automatically get a right to something else. That's the positive position. It's *far* easier to prove a positive, than the negative, so please find something that at least indicates you're correct for the general case, not just your one purchase. If you want a more detailed answer from from a legal POV, you could ask on [law.se].

Comment: @Makyen: I don't come on MathOverflow to argue with strangers about the law. I come here to do mathematics. I am confident that, when I own a copy of a math paper (e.g. from library download), I can freely download as many other copies of that paper as I like, from any source. When my co-author asks a question, and it's answered in a paper, I freely email him a copy of that paper, knowing that he could just as well get it at his library. Slavish fear of publishing companies should not stand in the way of research getting done. I'm done with this interaction now. Have a nice day!

Comment: Sci-hub also has a nice telegram bot @scihubot, you just paste doi and it gives a paper. No need to look for currently not closed mirror etc.

Answer (score 6):

The two answers posted summarize most of the comments, but miss two important ones.

1. Go to the [University of Chicago library website](https://www.lib.uchicago.edu/). Click "My Account" in the upper left. Login with your University of Chicago credentials. Contact your librarian if you struggle with this. Once you are logged in, you can access many articles electronically (and also MathSciNet, but that's not what you asked about).
2. Use a VPN. This will make it appear to the University of Chicago servers that you are on campus, and you can then access library resources as usual. [Instructions on how to do this at UChicago are here](https://its.uchicago.edu/2018/09/11/training-tip-cvpn/).

All that said, I also think you are not violating copyright if you find pdfs of articles from other sources in this situation, even so-called "pirate" sources, because you already have the rights to the articles in question through your affiliation to UChicago.

Comment: None of these options will work: `I have just graduated from the University of Chicago`

Comment: I still have access to my PhD university library, with the same username and password. For grad students, I thought it was standard practice to keep your  old login information?

Comment: @DavidWhite Alumni access for bachelor's graduates at my university, at least, is nothing more than what the public is allowed; although to be fair the sample size (1) is small. I did *not* downvote your answer, and do still agree with the idea of asking until someone says no.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not from a related field, but you might also find a lot of stuff quite comfortably via the Firefox add-on 'unpaywall'.

Answer (score 2):

This is just to confirm that, as announced earlier here, https://zbmath.org/ became open in 2021.